# What is meaning that men were prostrating themselves in Ezekiel 8:16?

Tags: ezekiel, definition

Does that particular word mean some type of Male satisfaction sexually?

> Eze 8:16 - Then He brought me into the inner courtyard of the LORD’S
> house. And behold, at the entrance to the temple of the LORD, between
> the porch and the altar, were about twenty-five men with their backs
> to the temple of the LORD while their faces were toward the east; and
> they were **prostrating** themselves eastward toward the sun. **NASB**

> Eze 8:16 - So He brought me to the inner court of the house of the
> LORD, and there at the entrance to the temple of the LORD, between the
> portico and the altar, were about twenty-five men with their backs to
> the temple of the LORD and their faces toward the east; and they were
> bowing to the east in **worship of the sun**. **BSB**

Comment: Welcome to BHSX.  Thanks for your contribution.  Please remember to take the tour (below left) to better understand how this site works.

Comment: The Hebrew word means 'worship' (KJV) or 'bow' (YLT). But if a version insists on the the word 'prostrate' (the verb) it means 'to throw oneself flat on the ground ... in reverence' [Oxford English Dictionary](https://www.oed.com/search?searchType=dictionary&q=prostrate&_searchBtn=Search) Your meaning is not present in the original or in the version.

Answer (score 1):

The operative verb translated "prostrating" by the NASB and "worshiping" by the BSB, is שָׁחָה (shachah) simply means to "bow down".  The meaning given by the BDB lexicon is:

> 1. bow down, prostrate oneself, before a monarch or superior, in homage, etc.
> 2. before God, in worship, etc.
> 3. before other [false] gods:

Such bowing often involved "prostrating" oneself; ie, lying flat on one's face in reverence toward a superior being as a sign of subservience and dependence.  It has no sexual connotation whatsoever.